# Docker image fails to run

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

We have a ASP.Net application that we run under Ubuntu 18.04 (with aspnetcore 2.2 installed, only runtime). We use the kestrel service to serve the app and nginx as the reverse proxy. Everything runs fine when installed in a VM/cloud instance.
Now, I'm looking to containerize our application (just testing waters). So, I built the an image using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install software-properties-common wget && \
wget -q -O /opt/packages-microsoft-prod.deb https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
dpkg -i /opt/packages-microsoft-prod.deb  && \
add-apt-repository universe  && \
apt-get update  && \
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https aspnetcore-runtime-2.2 nginx 

COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

COPY appfolder /opt/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/opt/appfolder/app.dll"]

EXPOSE 80:80
```

But, when I try to run the image, I get the following error:

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK
>   from:  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Any idea what could be going wrong? My assumption is (being new to the Docker world): 
 Use Ubuntu 18.04 as base image and install Dotnet and Nginx on top, then copy the nginx default site and run the app (using dotnet). Apparently, I'm missing something.

Comment: One way to debug the image is to run it with `... --entrypoint=/bin/bash [image]`. Then, from the shell, check that your app files are where you expect them, then try running the DLL.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, that is a good idea. Will try it out today.

Comment: Just tried it and Docker runs it and exits immediately. No error, no nothing. Even the return code is 0 indicating there are no errors.

Comment: Well, that's a problem! :-) You may try bumping the verbosity: `--verbosity` and either `d`etailed or `diag`nostic. If you repro the `DOCKERFILE` commands using a VM, does it work? One thing I'm curious about is that you say you're using Nginx as a proxy but you're only running the `dotnet` process with the DLL. Something's amiss there. I apologize that my .NET foo is limited.

Comment: Will try verbosity. I did end up changing the Dockerfile a bit now. Instead of all those run commands, I created a script (verified it worked in my vm), copied and ran it. This seemed to be a bit better. Also, for docker run command, looks like adding a -t (allocate pesudo terminal) and -i (interactive shell) seemed to make a difference and are providing me the shell to work with. 
I missed adding the service nginx start first, but added it later (though that was not the issue). :-)

Comment: Your Dockerfile as above is clean and well-structured. Yes to running `--interactive --tty`. Yes, Nginx is not the main issue but I wondered whether there were a red-herring somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft document [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/runtime-2.2.2).

You need to run

`sudo apt-get update`

after

`sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https`

and before

`sudo apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-2.2`

Comment: Not sure that is an issue at all, because when I run these commands from within the container, everything runs as expected.

Comment: I think it's because at the time you run the commands in the container `apt-transport-https` has already installed when you build the image.

Comment: Ok , nevermind, i tried with a VM and it worked as you said.